# django form is not validating

Tags: python, html, django, forms

So I have been trying to implement a way to post a project post in my website. However, it seems that there is something wrong with my validation with forms. Even if the form is correct and complete, it still wont validate.

No posts are being made in my projects page and nothing gets added in my database. I am not sure what is going on.

I don't see any errors in my terminal.

My code is below:

views.py

```
class CreateProjectsView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        p_photos = P_Images.objects.all()
        #project_form = ProjectsForm(initial=self.initial)
        project_form = ProjectsForm()
        context = {
            'p_photos': p_photos,
            'project_form': project_form,
        }
        return render(self.request, 'projects/forms.html', context)

    def post(self, request):
        project_form = ProjectsForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        p_formset = P_ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        # Checks if the project_form is valid before save
        if project_form.is_valid():
            instance = project_form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.save()

        # Checks if multiple image upload is valid before save
        if p_formset.is_valid(): 
        #if project_form.is_valid() and p_formset.is_valid():   
            #instance = project_form.save(commit=False)
            #instance.user = request.user
            #instance.save()
            images = p_formset.save(commit=False)
            images.save()

            data = {
                'is_valid': True, 
                'name': images.p_file.name, 
                'url': images.p_file.url
            }

        else:
            data = {
                'is_valid': False,
            }

        return JsonResponse(data)
```

forms.html

```
{% extends "projects/test.html" %}

{% block javascript %}

<form action="{% url 'create_post:retrieve_projects' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    {% csrf_token %}  

    {% for hidden in project_form.hidden_fields %}
    {{ hidden }}
    {% endfor %}

    {% for field in project_form %}
    {{ field }} <br />
    {% endfor %}

    <input type="submit" value="OK">

{% load static %}

{# JQUERY FILE UPLOAD SCRIPTS #}
<script src="{% static 'projects/js/jquery-file-upload/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'projects/js/jquery-file-upload/jquery.iframe-transport.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'projects/js/jquery-file-upload/jquery.fileupload.js' %}"></script>

{# PHOTOS PAGE SCRIPTS #}
<script src="{% static 'projects/js/basic-upload.js' %}"></script>

{# 1. BUTTON TO TRIGGER THE ACTION #}
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary js-upload-photos">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span> Upload photos
</button>

{# 2. FILE INPUT TO BE USED BY THE PLUG-IN #}
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="p_file" multiple
       style="display: none;"
       data-url="{% url 'create_post:create_projects' %}"
       data-form-data='{"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>

{# 3. TABLE TO DISPLAY THE UPLOADED PHOTOS #}
<table id="gallery" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Photo</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for p_photo in p_photos %}
      <tr>
        <td><a href="{{ p_photo.file.url }}">{{ p_photo.file.name }}</a></td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>

    <h1>hahahaha</h1>

</form>

{% endblock %}
```

This has been plaguing me for 2 weeks now. Its starting to discourage me from learning django in python :(

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: no, not at all, at least in my terminal. It's just that nothing happens

Comment: And you're sure everything you type in the form is valid? Add `{{ field.errors }}` under `{% for field in project_form %}` and try submitting the form then.

Comment: Also, your form action is pointing to `create_post:retrieve_projects` -- should it be pointing to `create_post:create_projects`?

Comment: I just added it, which won't let me go through if there is no value, but I still have the same issue. and oh! it is "create_post:retrieve_projects" so that I click the ok button it will send me back to my main page where all projects posted will be listed

Comment: Hey you know what? I just changed it to create_projects and it is finally working! How do i rate your comment? I would like to give you a star or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form action is pointing to `create_post:retrieve_projects` change it so it points to `create_post:create_projects`